# CUPP (pentest) on google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Do you see any limitations for cupp (http://www.securityfocus.com/tools/7320) running on GAE?

Answer (score 2):

I see a few problems right off:

- You'll need to create a web interface to the script
- GAE does not allow long running tasks and this looks like it could take a while.  You'd need to recode it to break the work up into chunks.
- Outbound FTP (for fetching word lists) is not supported on GAE
- Local file write access is not supported (you'd need to convert this to use the datastore)